# Installing double MapGuide in same computer?

Tags: installation, mapguide

Can I install two MapGuide Open Source with different version in the same computer?

For example, I have installed MapguideOpenSource 2.6 in my computer, then I want to install another version of Mapguide that is MapguideOpenSource 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're a Windows user. From the [installer instructions](http://trac.osgeo.org/mapguide/wiki/Release/3.1/Notes#Installernotes):

> Installing MGOS 3.1 (via the windows installer) alongside any older
>   release is not a currently supported configuration.Consider using the
>   MgInstantSetup bundle instead if you desire side-by-side installation

Earlier installer instructions are similar.

So you should choose one of the InstantSetup bundles (32 bit or 64 bit, depending on your system). It doesn't really matter what combination of versions, but you should only use the MgInstantSetup bundle. Since you have 2.6 already installed, you can install 3.0 from MgInstantSetup.

Another options would be to do the second install on a virtual machine.